# Annotating flag emojis to 3166 country codes in splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

Given a bunch of `countrycode` / `percent` results, decorate a pie chart with the flag of each country.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be anything built into splunk for this yet, but [here](https://gist.github.com/johan/f203bc1b83500ad6f1506d5a8363e0aa)'s how I constructed mine, based on already having upper-case `countrycode` inputs like `US`, `DE`, `AU`, and so on, for my own future reference:

```
… | eval flag = printf("%c%c", 127452 + tonumber(substr(countrycode,1,1), 36),
                               127452 + tonumber(substr(countrycode,2,1), 36)),
         country=countrycode+" ("+percent+"%) "+flag
```

[image: country code pie chart in splunk]